# Running a Timer Job

Tags: timer-jobs

I have a custom Timer Job that runs on every Monday.  However, I want to be able to run the timer job manually outside of Central admin.  but I dont want to use PowerShall or stsadm.  Can I put a link or a button on my site collection/SharePoint site and when someone clicks that link the timer job should run?

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: Just to be sure - SharePoint 2010/2013 or SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 3):

You can write similar code on your button click :

```
      SPSite site = new SPSite([your-site-url]);

        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
        {
            if (job.Name == "YouTimerjobname")
                job.RunNow();
        }
```

Comment: using(SPSite site = new SPSite([your-site-url])) should be used as you are creating a new instance of SPSite that needs to be disposed.

Comment: I used the code you gave and created an webpart with a button. But when I click the button i get a error "The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. "??

Comment: try the code using SPsecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: this is the code i am using now, can plz tell me wht iam doing wrong?

Comment: protected void btn_sendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://xxxxxxxsiteURLxxxxx"))
                {foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
                    {if (job.Name.Equals("Email"))
                      job.RunNow();
                    }}
            });
        }

Comment: did you deploy your dll to GAC?

Comment: Hi Amit, I found another work around and it worked perfectly. I just had to add a piece of code in the begging of my timer job and it. Just need to create this function before the Execute function. protected override bool HasAdditionalUpdateAccess() { return true; }

Answer (score 0):

You can start a timer job by code. So you can create a web part with a button. When a user clicks the button the 'onclick' code of the button starts the job.

Add the web part to a page and/or set security on the page so that only you can access it.